# Improve format in windows 2008 service

Tags: windows, service, date-formatting, 4d-database

I have a big issue, I have windows server 2008 R2, when I start a program (4D server) it takes the date format from system configuration (`dd/mm/yyyy`) but when I start the same program using a system service 4D Sever sets  the date format to `mm/dd/yyyy`. I can not understand this because the system date is set to (`dd/mm/yyyy`)

Any Ideas to resolve it? Is it possible to set a date format to the default user that runs the service? or maybe change the default date format to a service in windows server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One of two solutions

1. Use 4D ISO Dates and String formatting to display
2. Set regional time zone based on accounts
   http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apply-regional-language-settings-reserved-accounts#1TC=windows-7

REF FROM

http://4d.1045681.n5.nabble.com/Wrong-Date-Format-on-Web-Server-td5730625.html

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe it seems that the date format settings in the user profile for the user that runs the service differs from that of the interactive user. So, you need to either:

1. Change which user which runs the service, or
2. Change the settings for the user that runs the service.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I agree with you .. but How Do I change the user that runs the service? How do I Change the settings for the user that runs the service?

Comment: Those are not programming questions any more. Go to the service control manager for the first Q. Log on as the user and change settings for the second Q. Although you are probably running the service as LocalSystem. Well, I'm guessing, but you did not say. I suggest that you try to work out which user runs which process and get a better picture as to what is really going on.

Comment: Sorry for my little knowledge in windows server, I work with Mac computers. As I see, I only have one user on windows server, the admin user, how to fix it?

Comment: This is the wrong place for that question. SO is for programming questions. Are you doing any programming, or are you just trying to run somebody else's program?

Comment: Sorry if I am wrong, I am a computer programmer, I am using SO to try to getting help with my issue.

Comment: I don't see any code though. All I see is you asking about server admin. And SO is the wrong place for that.